# JavaScript - 'this' pointer gets undefined when being inside a function

Tags: javascript

I've defined `this.username` already; however, when being inside a function it get `undefined` how can I retrieve its value?

```
 Parse.User.logIn(this.username, this.password, {
   success: function(user) {

       //gets undefined
       console.log('username is : ', this.username);

    }});
```

Answer (score 1):

it's because that callback has a different scope compared to the outer function.

save a reference of `this` outside the function

```
var self = this;
```

then use `self` inside the function.

Comment: Got you! It worked, thanks a lot !

Comment: no problem. you're welcome :)